# DataView.RowFilter in a For Loop C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

Surprisingly, while filtering a `DataTable` within a `For Loop` using `DataView.RowFilter`, `Sytem.Data.DataView` returns a value for `i= 0` (*i.e. filter works as expected*) whereas it is `empty` for `i>0`. Below is an illustration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fruitid.Length; i ++)
{
    DataTable dnt = new DataTable();
    dnt = dr.ReadSSData(date, extension); // no issue so far
    DataView dvv = new DataView(dnt);
    dvv.RowFilter = "FRUIT = " + "'" + fruitid[i] + "'" + 
                    " AND BASIS_IND ='A'";
    dnt.Clear(); // i've cleared dnt, reset it even deleted 
    //dvv to ensure the filter gets 
    //re-initialized after each increment, but 
    //it does not improve the situation
}
```

However while *inefficiently* filtering the `DataTable` out of the `for loop` and by `hard-coding` the filter `n` times and also by creating new `DataView objects` such as:

```
DataTable dnt = new DataTable();
dnt = dr.ReadSSData(date, extension);

DataView dvv = new DataView(dnt);
dvv.RowFilter = "FRUIT = 'Apple' AND BASIS_IND ='A'";

DataView dvv2 = new DataView(dnt);
dvv2.RowFilter = "FRUIT = 'Orange' AND BASIS_IND ='A'";
```

the `filters` (`dvv` and `dvv2`) work well.

Thanks in advance for the explanation of this `weird` phenomenon.
Best,

Comment: What is _fruitid_? How is declared and initialized? Also the creation and initialization for the datatable is invariant, it should stay outside the loop as well the creation of the DataView. And you can remove the Clear at the end

Comment: `string[] fruitid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Fruit"].Split(',')`;

Comment: @TimSchmelter : to ensure that nothing gets wrong, if one use same command but without the `for loop` and create as many `DataView objet` as the size of the `string[]` one would end up with `values`.

Comment: @Steve: after significant investigation's time, I've realized the issue has been coming from the `App.config`. As a matter of fact, there has been hidden spaces in `<add key ="Fruit" value="Apple, Orange, etc." />`  thus making `fruitid[i]` untraceable (particularly for `i>0`) from the `loop` as opposed to 'hard-coding' solution.

Comment: Well, that's explain all. _fruitid[i].Trim()_ and add the option to RemoveEmptyEntries to your Split from the AppSettings values.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the tip, much appreciated.

Comment: In relation to Steve's latest comments, and in case it helps in the future people facing a similar issue, a single-line command to be used:`string[] fruitid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Fruit"].Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray();`